# Responsive pop up container

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i made a pop up window when the user clicks the book now button. It is working fine but i wanted to make it responsive just like the rest of the website. Currently i have set the conatiner height to a fixed height of 70vh. But if i want to change this value to fit-content so it responds to how much space the content needs the img on the left disapears. Now when i add some text to the pop-up-large-img div it does show the img. Now i dont know why it doesnt see a background img a content. But is there any other way to fix this without having to add content to my HTML.

```js
const ParisDetailButton = document.getElementById('button-paris');
const ParisPopUp = document.querySelector('.pop-up-paris');
const CloseButton = document.querySelector('.close-button');

ParisDetailButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ParisPopUp.classList.add('pop-up-active');
});

CloseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  ParisPopUp.classList.remove('pop-up-active');
});
```

```css
/* -------------- */
/* resets         */
/* -------------- */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* -------------- */
/* variables      */
/* -------------- */

:root {
  /* color */
  --orange: #f0932b;
  --hovered-orange: #ebb579;
  --white: #fff;
  --black: #000;
  --shadow-black: #0000001a;
  
  /* fonts */
  --ff-h1: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;
  --ff-h2: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  --ff-p: 'Segoe UI',Tahoma,Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;

  /* fontsizes */
  --fs-h1: 1.5rem;
  --fs-h2: 1.3rem;
  --fs-h3: 1.2rem;
}

/* -----------------*/
/* utility classes  */
/* -----------------*/

.heading-1 {
  font-family: var(--ff-h1);
  font-size: var(--fs-h1);
}

.heading-2 {
  font-family: var(--ff-h2);
  font-size: var(--fs-h2);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: var(--orange);
}

.heading-3 {
  font-family: var(--ff-h1);
  font-size: var(--fs-h3);
}

.paragraph {
  font-family: var(--ff-p);
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* -------------- */
/* header         */
/* -------------- */

header {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 100px;
}

.header-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.border {
  border-right: solid var(--white) 1px;
}

.styled-link {
  font-family: var(--ff-p);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--white);
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

header img {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.toggle-button {
  margin-left: 60px;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 21px;
  width: 30px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* ------------------ */
/* header responsive  */
/* ------------------ */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }

  .header-links {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* -------------- */
/* main           */
/* -------------- */

main {
  margin: 60px 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.card {
  min-height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid var(--shadow-black) 1px;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px var(--shadow-black);
}

.card-img > img {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.card-text {
  padding: 10px;
}

.card-text > h1 {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.card-text > h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button {
  color: var(--white);
  background-color: var(--orange);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: ease-in-out 200ms;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--shadow-black);
  background-color: var(--hovered-orange);
}

aside {
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid var(--shadow-black) 1px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.side-card {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.side-card-img  > img {
  max-width: 200px;
}

aside > h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* ----------------- */
/* main responsive   */
/* ----------------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  aside {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

/* -------------- */
/* footer         */
/* -------------- */

footer {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  color: var(--white);
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------- */
/* pop up styles  */
/* -------------- */

.pop-up-paris {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: var(--white);
  border: 2px solid var(--shadow-black);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px var(--shadow-black);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pop-up-active {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pop-up-large-img {
  background-image: url('/images/pop-up-imgs/paris.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
}

.pop-up-main {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}

.pop-up-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.pop-up-hotel-pictures {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.hotel-picture {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.hotel-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0px 50px 20px 0px;
  width: 33%;
}

.hotel-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0px 50px 20px 0px;
  width: 33%;
}

.hotel-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0px 50px 20px 0px;
  width: 33%;
}

.hotel-info-text {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: solid 2px var(--orange);
}

.close-button {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  border: solid 1px var(--shadow-black);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 25px;
  font-size: var(--fs-h2);
  color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.close-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: var(--hovered-orange);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Meta tags -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Link css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <!-- Title -->
  <title>City Guide - Wanderlust</title>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- pop ups -->
  <div class="pop-up-paris">

    <!-- img container -->
    <div class="pop-up-large-img">

    </div>

    <!-- content container -->
    <div class="pop-up-main">

      <!-- header -->
      <div class="pop-up-header">
        <div class="pop-up-header-text">
          <h1 class="heading-1">Paris</h1>
          <h2 class="heading-2">Recommended Hotels and B&B's</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="pop-up-header-button">
          <button class="close-button">&times</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- hotels -->
      <div class="pop-up-hotel-pictures">
        <div class="hotel-1">
          <div class="hotel-picture"></div>
          <p class="hotel-info-text paragraph">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi pariatur, explicabo hic fugit tempora maxime quae ut consequuntur rerum neque repellendus praesentium! Impedit eveniet omnis ducimus ipsa, eum molestiae velit error placeat ipsam.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="button paragraph">$120</a>
        </div>
        <div class="hotel-2">
          <div class="hotel-picture"></div>
          <p class="hotel-info-text paragraph">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi pariatur, explicabo hic fugit tempora maxime quae ut consequuntur rerum neque repellendus praesentium! Impedit eveniet omnis ducimus ipsa, eum molestiae velit error placeat ipsam.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="button paragraph">89$</a>
        </div>
        <div class="hotel-3">
          <div class="hotel-picture"></div>
          <p class="hotel-info-text paragraph">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi pariatur, explicabo hic fugit tempora maxime quae ut consequuntur rerum neque repellendus praesentium! Impedit eveniet omnis ducimus ipsa, eum molestiae velit error placeat ipsam.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="button paragraph">290$</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- header -->
  <header>
    <img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Logo Wanderlust">

    <!-- hamburger menu -->
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>

    <!-- header links -->
    <div>
      <ul class="header-links">
        <li><a href="#" class="styled-link border">Destinations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="styled-link border">Flights</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="styled-link">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- main content -->
  <div class="main-container">
    <main>

      <div class="main-content">

        <div class="card">

          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="./images/paris.jpg" alt="Paris">
          </div>

          <div class="card-text">
            <h1 class="heading-1">Parijse beauty</h1>
            <h2 class="heading-2">The city of lights</h2>
            <p class="paragraph">
              Parijzenaars zelf duiden de stad weleens informeel aan met Paname. als de lichtstad of de stad van de
              liefde.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="button paragraph" id="button-paris">boek nu</a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card">

          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="./images/amsterdam.jpg" alt="Paris">
          </div>

          <div class="card-text">
            <h1 class="heading-1">I Amsterdam</h1>
            <h2 class="heading-2">The city of freedom</h2>
            <p class="paragraph">
              er is geen stad als Amsterdam zo ruim en zo vertrouwd; als ik een huis te bouwen had, ik had het hier
              gebouwd met vensters waar al ’t licht door stroomt, dat van den Amstel slaat, wanneer de winter ’t water
              stremt en ’t volk te schaatsen gaat.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="button paragraph">boek nu</a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="card">

          <div class="card-img">
            <img src="./images/prague.jpg" alt="Paris">
          </div>

          <div class="card-text">
            <h1 class="heading-1">Once Upon Prague</h1>
            <h2 class="heading-2">City of a Hundred Spires</h2>
            <p class="paragraph">
              Praag wordt als een van de mooiste steden van Europa beschouwd. Het historische centrum staat op de
              Werelderfgoedlijst van UNESCO
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="button paragraph">boek nu</a>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <aside>

        <h2 class="heading-2">must see</h2>

        <div class="side-card">
          <div class="side-card-img">
            <img src="./images/amsterdam.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="side-card-text">
            <h3 class="heading-3">Amsterdam</h3>
            <p class="paragraph">Feel the spacy vibe around amsterdam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="side-card">
          <div class="side-card-img">
            <img src="./images/budapest.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="side-card-text">
            <h3 class="heading-3">Budapest</h3>
            <p class="paragraph">Feel the spacy vibe around amsterdam</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="side-card">
          <div class="side-card-img">
            <img src="./images/lisboa.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="side-card-text">
            <h3 class="heading-3">Lisaboa</h3>
            <p class="paragraph">Feel the spacy vibe around amsterdam</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </aside>

    </main>
  </div>

  <!-- footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <p class="paragraph">Arteveldehogeschool 2019</p>
      <p class="paragraph">Credits images <a href="#">unsplash</a></p>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- script link -->
  <script src="/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, image height becomes 0 if you change height to fit-content in pop-up-paris class. And you want it to get the available height instead.

My Solution:

Change height to fit-content in pop-up-paris class as you said.

Change height to 100vh from 100% in pop-up-large-img class.

[image: Result]

Comment: so this does make the img show up but the pop up should not be 100vh it should only take up about 70% of the screen height. Now if i change it to 70vh it makes the img fit perfectly. The only problem is that once you make your window smaller it doesnt scale properly

Comment: Forget about it then. Try this: align-items: inherit in pop-up-active class, height: fit-content in pop-up-paris class, remove height: 100% from pop-up-large-img class

Comment: it didnt work for me either. I solved the issue with javascript thnx for your help